# I have a list of inputs type file and it accept image only .. How can i view an image every time i add one? using onchange method

Tags: javascript, html, image, onchange

i wrote this code and its working but when i choose image it only appear in front of the first element .

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Change image on select new image from file input</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" onchange="loadFile(event)">
            <img class="output" width="100px" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" onchange="loadFile(event)">
            <img class="output" width="100px" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" onchange="loadFile(event)">
            <img class="output" width="100px" />
        </li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var output = document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0];
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
</script>
```

I just want every image to appear in front of its input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're overloading on the first `<img>` element every time the file changes. It's better you find the `<img>` next to the target input element:

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

EDIT: to include for your question in the comment

To create new `input` elements in `JS` and implement the same behavior as the other `input` elements, you will need to create not just the input element but the whole `li` node just like the structure of the existing html and append it to the `ul` in the `DOM`. Note that if the html structure changes, `nextElementSibling` may fail to find the corresponding `img` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var output = event.target.nextElementSibling;
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };

    const input = document.createElement('INPUT'); 
    input.type = 'file'; 
    input.accept = '.png, .jpg, .jpeg'; 
    input.onchange = loadFile;

    const img = document.createElement('IMG'); 
    img.width = '100';

    const li = document.createElement('LI'); 
    li.appendChild(input);
    li.appendChild(img);

    const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    ul.appendChild(li);

</script>
```

Comment: OK thanks it's working , One more question !
if i want to create new input file and i want it to have the same thing as the original <li>
elements ?

i tried that 
```input.onchange = loadFile;
```
but its not working for the new inputs at all

Comment: Do you create the new input using javascript or is it rendered using html like the other elements?

Comment: using javascript .. here is the code
```
var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'file';
        input.accept = '.png, .jpg, .jpeg';
        input.onchange = loadFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery, you can add as many input as you want.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Change image on select new image from file input</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
      <img class="output" width="100px" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
      <img class="output" width="100px" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
      <img class="output" width="100px" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[type=file]").on("change", function(e) {
      $(this).next().attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    })
  </script>
```